# Ignore certain songs in Zune

Tags: zune, music, zune-player

I know you can dislike a song (broken heart symbol), but the song will occasionally pop up when I'm listening in shuffle mode. Is there a way to put audio files (stand-up comedy in this case) onto my phone so that I can listen to it only when I explicitly choose to (never pops up during shuffle mode)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Zune desktop application you can make a new *Autoplaylist*. You have two easy options, either dislike your comedy tracks, or make sure that your comedy tracks have the correct genre e.g. *stand-up comedy* (this option would be the best).

1. Open Zune
2. Click *collection\MUSIC*
3. On the right click *PLAYLISTS*
4. Click *new autoplaylist*
5. Give the playlist a name. For rating select *Like or unrated* **or** exclude the *stand-up comedy* genre..
6. Leave the rest of the defaults and click *OK*.
7. Sync your device.
8. On your device play the playlist and turn shuffle on.